# What is the groupId parameter in the IContentManager.BuildDisplay method of Orchard for?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

The method `IContentManager.BuildDisplay` used to call to the drivers of a ContentItem has an optional groupId argument.
I have navigated through the source code but I did not understand exactly what is its use case. It seems to be able to filter shapes, but I'm not sure I understand how.

Could you clarify this for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this parameter is used for filtering shapes. You can provide an optional parameter via **.OnGroup()** method of ContentShape object returned from Display/Editor method of a driver.

By default it's an empty string. If you provide a groupId parameter in BuildDisplay - **only the shapes with that group id specified would be taken into account** when building the final output.

I found it particularly useful when needed to render **the same part differently in different scenarios** - returning a *Combined* result with ContentShape objects (each with different group specified) in it from the driver's Display method.

*Remember that if you explicitly specify a group in BuildDisplay method - **only** the shapes with that group set will be used.*

Comment: True. This group is currently used to handle the tabs in admin pages if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will prove pretty useful.

Comment: @Bertrand: Your're right - it's currently used to handle site settings menu sub-items in Dashboard.

Comment: Is it possible to apply this grouping to Fields? I tried using OnGroup on the Part which contains the Fields, but only the Part editor displayed, not the Fields (which makes sense as they use different Drivers).

Comment: Is calling .OnGroup(x) the same as specifying @MyGroup in Placement.info?